# Can I force the browser to include the Origin header?

Tags: cors, http-headers

NB: I'm not trying to *override* the value of the Origin header, just force the browser to include it where it normally doesn't.

We have an [AAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAA_(computer_security)) system that controls access to our server's resources. The security system allows same-origin access generally, and cross-origin access only when it sees a specific combination of HTTP Origin header value and a specific target domain name.

This works well, but it would appear that browsers don't consider CSS url() URLs as cross-origin, even when the access really does originate from a different origin, and thus do not send an Origin header. Our AAA-check fails, and button background images do not load.

We can still use the Referer header, but that header may be overridden and would prefer not having to rely on it.

Is there any method that I can use to to trick the browser into sending the Origin header for this background image?

Comment: No, you cannot. Another possibility would be to rely on Fetch Metadata request headers, but they're not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @jub0bs If you format your commend as an answer, I'll accept it and close this questoin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fetch standard [states](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header) under which conditions compliant browsers add an [`Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) to a request:

1. the request’s response tainting is `cors`, or
2. the request’s mode is `websocket`, or
3. the request’s method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`.

For subresource loads like styles and scripts,

1. the request's response tainting is `basic` (not `cors`), and
2. the request’s mode is `no-cors` (not `websocket`), and
3. the request's method is `GET`.

Therefore, none of the sufficient conditions are fulfilled for an `Origin` header to be attached to the requests of interest to you. Short of forcing your users to rely on a non-compliant browser, you cannot force the `Origin` header to be attached to the requests of interest to you.

---

The `Referer` header is unreliable, because a document can, via a strict [Referrer policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy), suppress it in requests it sends.

---

You may want to consider relying on [Fetch Metadata request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Fetch_metadata_request_header) (the [`Sec-Fetch-Site` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site), in particular) but, at the time of writing this answer, they're only supported in Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer! I have a followup concerning Sec-Fetch-Site. If the resource fetch is initiated due to `background-image: url(...)` in CSS, how can Sec-Fetch-Site help me? I don't think I can influence that fetch, can I? (BTW, we resorted to Referer header and limited the bypass to images only, which is not a problem for us, even if that header were to be tampered with)